# How to handle input events on custom input component in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-custom-component

I'm trying to create a custom Input component using Reative Form in `Angular 7` but i'm having trouble passing events to the input field.

My `component` has a label and an input field and a specific layout. My `component html` looks like **this**:

```html
<div id="customInputGroup"  [formGroup]="parentFormGroup" [ngClass]="{'input-value': hasValue()}">
    <label [for]="inputId">{{label}}</label>
    <input [id]="inputId"  [name]="inputName"  class="form-control" [placeholder]="placeholder" [formControlName]="inputName" [mask]="mask">
</div>
```

And in **my `Component`**:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-field',
  templateUrl: './input-field.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-field.component.css']
})
export class InputFieldComponent implements OnInit {


  @Input('placeholder') placeholder = '' ;
  @Input('label') label = '';
  @Input('inputId') inputId = '';
  @Input('inputName') inputName = '';
  @Input('parentFormGroup') parentFormGroup:FormGroup;
  @Input('mask') mask;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  hasValue(){
    return (this.parentFormGroup.get(this.inputName).value != undefined 
    && this.parentFormGroup.get(this.inputName).value != null 
    && this.parentFormGroup.get(this.inputName).value != '')
  }
```

Everything was working fine till i had to handle an input `onBlur` event(or it could be any other input event).
The result i want is to call my `component` passing any event like **this**:

```
<app-input-field (blur)="functionName()"></app-input-field>
```

or

```
<app-input-field (keyup)="functionName()"></app-input-field>
```

And my `component` will be able to pass these events to my input field 'dynamically'. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: InputFieldComponent  should implement ControlValueAccessor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for blur event you need to create a eventemitter with the same name and emit this event on input elemnt blur emit

```
export class InputFieldComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() blur:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter(); // 

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

*template*

```
<input type="text" (blur)="blur.emit($event)"  >
```

app.template

```html
<app-input-field (blur)="onBlur($event)" (keyup)="onKeyup($event)"></app-input-field>
```

> we did this for the blur event because the event is not bubble where the keyup will work without create any custom event because it bubble.

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bg64as)

you can implement two way data binding like this

```
  @Input() value:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  @Output() valueChange:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

*template*

```
<app-input-field  [(value)]="name" ></app-input-field>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e3vtui)

> any bubble event like input,keypress,keyup,keydown you can capture on the element itself or you can work around it like what we did on blur event.

Answer (score 5):

Events like `blur` works on `input field` , not selectors like `<app-input-field>`

You can emit event for all events like blur, keyup, mouseover etc..

**InputFieldComponent**:

HTML:

```
<input (blur)="functionName('blur')" (keyup)="functionName('keyUp')" [id]="inputId"  [name]="inputName"  class="form-control" [placeholder]="placeholder" [formControlName]="inputName" [mask]="mask">
```

TS:

```
@Output() OnInputEvent= new EventEmitter();

functionName(eventName) {
    this.OnInputEvent.emit(eventName);
}
```

In your **component**:

```
<app-input-field (OnInputEvent)="functionName($event)"></app-input-field>
```

TS:

```
functionName(event) {
    switch (event) {
       case "blur":
       ...
       break;

       case "keyUp":
       ...
       break;
    }
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mrfhx2)**

Comment:  you did a good job @Adrita ,for keyup event you don't need to do anything it will bubble and you can catch it on the element itself but blur not , check my answer ☕

Comment: Thanks @malbarmawi , your solution is also great. But I just think that by emitting all the events from output, they can be handled in the same  place

Comment:  both of ours answer are correct and can combine both together  , I do like the idea of compose all event in single event , up 

Comment: but if the component gone to use as wrapper for input element and will be use in reactive form he must implement ControlValueAccessor , I think 

Comment: @malbarmawi Yeah... We are discussing it ourselves but the one who asked the question haven't used any of the answer I guess :D  By the way thank you, it's not everyday somebody who has an answer appreciating another answer

Comment: Yeah I have read about `ControlValueAccessor` but never really used it, may be you can add an answer using it, I would get to learn about it